# Django 'context' for function-based and class-based views

Tags: django, django-context

Help me understand how to use Django's `context`--Is the issue related to the use of `context` in function-based vs class-based views:

I have created two views (`index` and `post_list`) and respective templates (following the Assessment portion of the [Mozilla Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/django_assessment_blog)). The code for `index` works, but identical code for `post_list` doesn't. Why is that?

## view #1

```
def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    num_posts = Post.objects.all().count()
    num_comments = Comment.objects.all().count()
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()
    num_commenters = Commenter.objects.count()        

context = {
        'num_posts': num_posts,
        'num_comments': num_comments,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
        'num_commenters': num_commenters,
        'post_list' : post_list,
    }
return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

## template #1 --Works:

```
{% block content %}
 <h1>Index:</h1>
This blog has a total of {{num_posts}} posts by {{ num_authors}} authors.

{% endblock %}
```

## view #2

```
class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    num_posts = Post.objects.all().count()
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

    context = {
        'num_posts': num_posts,
        #'num_authors': num_authors,     # Removed b/c it doesn't work
        'post_list' : post_list,
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['num_authors'] = Author.objects.count() # But this works!
        return context #edited, this line was left out in the original post
```

## template#2 - not totally working:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>All Posts:</h1>

This blog has a total of {{num_posts}} posts by {{ num_authors}} authors.

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your `get_context_data` method does not seem to be returning the `context` dictionary. When invoked at runtime, it's returning `None`. Add `return context` at the bottom of the method definition.

Comment: @abdou I l accidentally left out the line `return context` for `get_context_data`, but it was in the code--doesn't help though.

Comment: Other than looking at the code, it's hard to spot what's not working. Are you getting errors or is the template not rendering with the proper values?

Comment: What is happening on the second case?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte In the second case, the value doesn't get rendered at all.

Comment: @Abdou No error, but the values don't show up.

Comment: Another block of code w similar issues:  The `context` block doesn't get rendered. But `context['authors'] = Author.objects.all()` works. 
   `authors = Author.objects.all()
    num_authors=Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'authors': authors,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['num_authors'] = Author.objects.count()
        context['authors'] = Author.objects.all() <br>
        return context`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the `get_context_data` method does not update all the variables you expect to be using within your template. For instance, the `context` class variable is not the same thing as the `context` variable you are returning inside the `get_context_data` method. Therefore, the only variable to which you have access in the template is `num_authors`. To make sure you have all the needed variables within your template, you need to edit `get_context_data` to update the `context` with the dictionary defined at the class level:

```
class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    num_posts = Post.objects.all().count()
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    context_vars = {
        'num_posts': num_posts,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
        'post_list' : post_list,
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(PostListView.context_vars)
        return context
```

Two main updates are made to your original code snippet: the class variable `context` is changed to `context_vars` to avoid conflicts and confusion; and the `context` variable within the `get_context_data` method is `updated` with the contents of `context_vars`. This will make sure that everything defined at the class level (i.e. `PostListView.context_vars`) makes it to your template.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks for the explanation--it clears up my confusion over how `context` gets passed into templates. I've done the tutorial several times and this is one of the areas that always trip me up. As with new learners, I find it hard to ask the right question. Appreciate your insight!